# How do i override the "addAction()" funciton under app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers

Tags: magento

I am trying to add some data to a session variable when a product is added to the shopping cart...

I tried copying the "CartController.php" under "app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers" to 
"local\Mage\Checkout\controllers" but its not actually overriding the controller..

Could anyone give me some hint on this..?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](http://xhtmlandcsshelp.blogspot.com/2010/11/magento-overwrite-cart-controller-add.html?showComment=1301033222046#c537869578363545798) , this enables us to override the CartController.php addAction() funciton... This is exaclty i needed.

Hope this would help someone in need.

Balan

Answer (score 1):

You can create an "Event Oberserver" to trigger an event.

Create the following folders :

- app/code/local/[myMagento]/EventTest/etc
- app/code/local/[myMagento]/EventTest/Model

create a file under /EventTest/Model directory like myMagento_EventTest.xml and put the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <config>
       <modules>
         <myMagento_EventTest>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </myMagento_EventTest>
      </modules>
   </config>
```

create config.xml file under /EventTest/etc folder nad put the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
      <config>
        <modules>
          <myMagento_EventTest>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
          </myMagento_EventTest>
        </modules>
        <frontend>
         <events>
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                   <myMagento_EventTest_Model_Observer>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>myMagento_EventTest_Model_Observer</class>
                      <method>MyTestMethod</method>
                   </myMagento_EventTest_Model_Observer>
               </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        </events>
      </frontend>
     </config>
```

create model class file observer.php under the /EventTest/Model directory and put following

```
<?php

class myMagento_EventTest_Model_Observer {
public function MyTestMethod($observer) {
$event = $observer->getEvent(); //Fetches the current event
$product = $event->getProduct();
$eventmsg = "Current Event Triggered : " . $event->getName() . "
Currently Added Product : " . $product->getName();
//Adds Custom message to shopping cart
echo Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->addSuccess($eventmsg);
//Your Custom Logic Here
//you can use print_r($product) here to get more details
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this logic.. Actually i am trying to pass some params in the addtocart url like "http://192.168.1.202:2020/magento/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovLzE5Mi4xNjguMS4yMDIvbWFnZW50by9jYXRhbG9nc2VhcmNoL3Jlc3VsdC8_cT1ETDYwNkE,/product/9/myparams/params" and retrieve this myparams in the "addAction" in "CartController.php"... so i need to override this controller.. if i copy this controller to local folder its not working.. any suggestion for this??

Comment: @balanv as you can see in the last code section, you should write your business logic in there. Did you do something for that? Sorry, I haven't got any idea about addAction.

Comment: Really what i need to store some of my custom params when a product is added to cart, i ll send this params in the url... Anyway thanks for your Eventlistener example.. i could use this somewhere its needed.... Thanks Oğuz ÇELİKDEMİR