# Magento - AJAX Call Product Page Elements to Category Page. Select Box Not Populated

Tags: ajax, magento, jquery, magento-1.5

I'm trying to create an ajax 'quick view' or 'quick cart' type feature on my Magento store. The kind of one where you hover over a product and have the option to 'quick view' it in a lightbox instead of going to the product page.

I'm using a very simple jQuery Ajax call like this:

```
$j('#ajaxquickviewcontent').load("http://websiteaddress/category/productname.html .product-view").ajaxComplete(function(){alert ('Done');});
```

With this method I get all of the content I'm after (i.e. product image, description, the configurable attribute options (size) dropdown, qty selector and add to cart buttons) - but the attribute option (size) dropdown isn't populated with any content. I just get the dropdown but with no options in it and obviously can't add any products to the cart.

If I change the call to load the whole product page, eg

```
$j('#ajaxquickviewcontent').load("http://websiteaddress/category/productname.html").ajaxComplete(function(){alert ('Done');});
```

Then the drop down does have the sizes. I'm assuming there is possibly some javascript on the page somewhere that I'm supposed to load as well but I can't find it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for what script I would be missing that would be outside of the product-essential div?

Comment: Are you actually calling the configurable item page by ID or the orphan item itself (which would have no configurable options)?

Comment: I'm calling the 'product-view' or 'product-essential' div from product page URL. So from the category page, the link is called into a variable from the onclick handler of that product and used in the ajax call above. I'm not using any controllers or anything outside of the standard Magento installation. I just find it strange that if I call the entire page it works, but if I only call the div that contains the product info I get nothing in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look @

[Magento Quick View Ajax Loader](https://github.com/czettnersandor/magento-quick-view-ajax)

http://ecommercedeveloper.com/articles/1875-create-a-quick-view-for-product-images/

Comment: I've not made a custom controller before. Would this require creating a new 'module'?
You get correct answer for those links - very helpful!