# how to add product options on a quick view popup?

Tags: magento, view, product

I'm working on a product quick view Megnto module. My only problem is how can I display the product options on my popup ?
In the Product View page  this how we call it :

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Can you help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713231/magento-ajax-call-product-page-elements-to-category-page-select-box-not-popul/13713636#comment18908223_13713636