# Combine list.phtml & view.phtml together

Tags: magento

Hello all i need to display product detail page right under category page so as you click on the category image it will display the same product details right under the same page.Also when user clicks on any category it comes with all products & with details of first item in list. Is it possible in magento & if yes then how can i do it. I am new in magento but it seems to me a great framework to work with. Please help me Thanks

Comment: Hello is there anyone who can help me with this, how to display both the ages together in list.phtml in magento please help

Comment: To clarify, you want to show the entire product page, including header, footer and sidebar beneath the category page?

Answer (score 1):

To show product detail page on category page you have to make ajax request and get the whole detail and insert into div located at bottom of category page.
Follow this link
 [Magento - AJAX Call Product Page Elements to Category Page. Select Box Not Populated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713231/magento-ajax-call-product-page-elements-to-category-page-select-box-not-popul)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i want to display first item of product list by default & if i filter from left navigation it must auto load the first item from category list. Your answer is great & it solves first part of my qustion please suggest how to tackle the second part as well thanks thnak you very much for your reply

Comment: Get the collection of products for current category and then load the model with the first product to get the detail of product.So you can search to get current category id and then get collection for products realted to that id and then load model with first item

Comment: After getting collection of products on List page you can function getFirstItem() to get first product.eg $collection->getFirstItem()